# Want to collect smartwatch sensor data. wanted interval is 0.05 second

Tags: android

I am studying to collect smartwatch sensor data. I succeeded in collecting the raw data with sample codes, but I can't handle the interval. I want to collect data which the interval is 0.05 sec.

How/where should I change the code?

Comment: We can't help you to “change the code” until after you show us the code.

Comment: i wanted to add codes but its hard to attach codes here. not comfortable using this site.

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the grammar and capitalisation. As @dour says, you need to include your code so that people can actually see the problem you are encountering; without the code no one can really help you.  Take a look at this page here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and the help pages here: http://stackoverflow.com/help to read up on this, but you can also just give it a go and someone may come back and edit like I have.